# Jquery push bar stay active after change page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu bar who get active/desactive when i click on it :

```
 <script>
   $("#menuheaderdrop").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    $("#header").toggleClass("toggled");


});


</script>
```

How can i let it active even if user change page of the site ? until he click on it again for desactive it

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#menuheaderdrop").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var $wrapper = $("#wrapper");
  
  if ($wrapper.hasClass('toggled')) {
    $wrapper.removeClass("toggled");
    $("#header").removeClass("toggled");
    //mark it not toggled in the storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('toggled', 'false');
  } else {
    $wrapper.addClass("toggled");
    $("#header").addClass("toggled");
    //mark it toggled in the storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('toggled', 'true');
  }
});

//if it was toggled previously, trigger the click on page load to toggle it on
if (sessionStorage.getItem('toggled') === 'true') {
  $("#menuheaderdrop").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Work like charm thanks ! There is a way to desactivate the animation of the menu only when he was toggled before ? cause the animation back again everytime

Comment: What animation?

Comment: -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;